# Understanding 3D space

Tags: math, 3d

I'm confusing myself terribly grasping the concept of plotting on a 3D plane, if I'm looking down the -Z axis, to put an objectinfront of me I just make the Z value Negative and to put it behind I just make it positive.. but.. how do I Put objects to my left or right? Sorry, I realise this is a stupid question but none the less it's confusing me

`Example`

I'm drawing a square at (-3,-2,10; -3, 2, 10; 3,-2, 10; 3, 2, 10) how would I draw something to its right or left hand side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the Z-axis the same, and move on the X-axis.

left and right is subjective offcourse, because it depends how you view it, but I assume you are looking flat at the x-y axis, and the z axis is "pointing away" from you.

So, in your case:
`(-3+a,-2,10; -3+a, 2, 10; 3+a,-2, 10; 3+a, 2, 10)` where a is how much you want to move it to the right

if you make a negative, it will shift to the left (on the X axis).

Because your starting point is -3, and your end point is 3, your Y-axis will be in the middle of your object. so your starting point should be 3, and endpoint 9 te be to the right of the object. -> a=+6

if you want to go to the left: (starting-point-previous-object) - (width of object) = (-3)-(6)=-9 -> a=-9

## To rotate objects

watch this [website](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/matrix/orthogonal/rotation/index.htm) it has a ver simple and basic explanation. I find it to be very readable

Comment: so, if I wanted to move it 90 degree's to the right what value would I give x?

Comment: For a right handed coordinate system, z would generally be coming out of the screen, so the viewer is looking down the -Z.

Comment: @bshields: very true, @Meowix: you dont move shapes with degree's, you rotate them.

If you want to rotate you should use sine and cosine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Comment: if you want to rotate, around what do you want to rotate? the plane around one of it's corners, or it's center ? ... Or the pint where your axis' start

Answer (score 3):

The X axis defines the left-right dimension, the Y axis defines the up-down dimension, with negative values to the left and down, positive values to the right and up.  So offset your drawing in the positive x direction (i.e. add some value to all of the x values in your square) to move it to the right.

Answer (score 3):

I drew something like this on a piece of paper:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ed.ac.uk](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVDICT/CVFIG5/img14.png))</sub>

Draw + and - onthe ends of the axis.  Helps keep track while punching in numbers.

In your case, it would be -Z moving away from you, or "into" the screen.

Comment: This is DirectX coordinate system (left-handed). In OpenGL(right-handed), when X points right and Y points up, Z axis points towards the viewer.

Comment: @SigTerm: There is no "DirectX coordinate system"  Both DirectX and OpenGL can use either left handed or right handed.

Comment: "Both DirectX and OpenGL can use either left handed or right handed" This is not exactly correct. By default DirectX uses left-handed, OpenGL uses right handed. It is possible to make API use different system, but it requires additional steps. Normally - flipping z in projection matrix, and changing triangle vertex order(cw vs ccw). Or switching face culling rule.

Comment: @SigTerm: no, it is exactly correct.  Both API's handle both coordinate systems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a *three dimensional cartesian coordinate system*, you have three perpendicular axis *X*, *Y* and *Z*.

Directions like right, left, top or front though are **always subjective** and can just be interpreted in relation to a *camera*. All operations with these coordinates (rotation, translation, vector maths in general) is **independent** of this view.

Now if you *define* a camera, you have defined the directions as well. A **common** definition (like used in *DirectX*) is the camera

- resides in the origin
- looks along the Z-axis
- has an upward direction along the Y-axis

Therefore right/left is defined through positive/negative X coordinates, same for up/down with Y or front/backwards direction on the Z-axis.

But this is never an absolute thing. Given another camera (e.g. rotated, moved), all looks different. Just look how things move when you look on them upside down.

This [image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Ray_trace_diagram.svg) shows pretty well how it all depends on the camera (why can't Stackoverflow handle .svg-graphics?)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the coordinate system used : Most textbooks use the right-handed. A few outcomers (DirectX, PBRT) use a left handed one.

In a right-handed coordinate system, your thumb is the x. The following axes come in the same order as the other fingers (Y = index, ...).

Now move your hand so that X is towards the right of the screen, Y is up, and Z is towards you. This will be how OpenGL "sees" the world.

That's pretty much all you need to *know*.

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates are (x,y,z).

You have described translating the square in the z plane by changing the z values.

Moving left or right is a translation in x - simply offset the x values.

Moving up and down is a translation in y - simply offset the y values.